# Как пишется слово "супер" в современной орфографии?

Tags: орфография

**Как писать формант "супер" в препозиции?** Согласно правилу, слитно, конечно, но наши российские пользователи в Сети это правило явно игнорируют, предпочитая раздельное или дефисное написание. Возможно, они не заглядывают в словари, а может быть, им так кажется правильнее. Какой-никакой, а глас народа.

**Супер - трудное слово.** С одной стороны, оно неплохо освоилось в языке и приобрело (пока в разговорной речи) функции существительного, прилагательного, наречия, с другой - **оно многозначно**, используется для высокой оценки качества, величины,  а также верхнего расположения. Русская приставка СВЕРХ, которая всегда пишется слитно, таких возможностей не имеет, и поэтому неудивительно такое разнообразие письма для  "супер".

Особенно часто слово  "супер" используется для **эмоционально-субъективной авторской оценки** качества существительных и прилагательных, и такие слова сложно найти в словаре (пишут их через дефис или раздельно), например: супер-профессионал, супер-мультик, супер-хит,  супер-хороший,  супер-приобретение, супер-качество,  супер-талант, супер-квартира, супер-режиссер, супер-красивый, супер-цивилизованный.

Кроме того, существуют **частные варианты**, требующие пояснения: супер-Марс (в астрономии), супер-Эго, супер-мега-адекватный, супер-перестраховщики-вредители.

Так можно ли утверждать, что СУПЕР [от лат. super - над, выше] - **это первая часть сложных слов, которая пишется всегда слитно**, или правило было изменено и дополнено?

Comment: суперпрофессионал

Слитно или раздельно? Орфографический словарь-справочник. — М.: Русский язык. Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998

Comment: Серж, суперпрофессионал - это более-менее понятно, профессионал среди  профессионалов,  а вот суперквартира (она же квартира супер) - это что такое?  Подобные сочетания вряд ли могут претендовать на место в словаре, и тогда это не приставка, а определение. Вот и Яндекс поправил "суперквартиру" на "супер квартиру". Вообще говоря, складывается впечатление, что нужно закрепить в словарях этот "английский" раздельный вариант.

Comment: Вы правы, Яндекс исправляет на раздельное написание. Лопатин считает "супер" приставкой. У Кузнецова два значения. Во втором значении:  ***первая часть сложных слов**. Во всех случаях пишется слитно.

Comment: Суперквартира - можно по-разному понимать: очень большая квартира и/или роскошная, богатая.

Comment: Вон Грамота.ру во всех значениях рекомендует слитное написание: ***суперъяхта***.

Comment: "Яндексу" с его программерами, прежде чем набиваться к живым людям в языковые авторитеты, нужно потренироваться над сочинением прилагальных, раз он ставит перед собой задачу раздельного написания неологизмов; для начала пусть окончание к своему "чебурашке" приделает и предлагает уже "суперская квартира" :) P. S. Гугл на "суперквартиру" не чихает - пусть "Яндекс" у него поучится ещё немного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, в составе других слов "супер-" (в значении "сверх-") должно писаться слитно (без дефиса); раздельное написание в таком значении воспринимаю как грубую ошибку, аналогичную отделению приставки от слова. Написание с дефисом возможно в авторских изысках с *множественными* префиксоидами, вроде "супер-мега-" и "супер-пупер-ещё-что-то-" поскольку здесь воедино сводятся альтернативные трактовки одного понятия (то ли супер-, то ли мега-), и автор не решается предпочесть одну другой, вываливая на читателя всё вместе - имеет право и на такое смутно-расшатанное самовыражение. Не всегда оправдано образование слов с русскими корнями там, где вместо "супер" возможно "сверх", например, давно освоенное слово "*суперзвезда*" мне видится бесполезным ввиду имеющегося "сверхзвезда". И только в значении оценочного восклицания (здорово, отлично и т. п.) "супер" выступает как отдельное слово.

Comment: Alex_ander,  интересно, что редактор подчеркнул слитно написанные примеры (их, конечно, нет в словаре), да и  бегло прочитать некоторые из них довольно затруднительно (суперррежиссер, суперпрофессионал), "супер" явно выступает здесь в функции определения (приложения), а не образует новое слово, суперкрасивая - это очень красивая, а не сверхкрасивая.  Надо бы как-то разобраться с семантикой подобных слов (например, гала-концерт, дефисное написания иноязычного определения). Кстати, сверхзвезда - это астр. термин, а суперзвезда - известный исполнитель, семантика слов разная.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно орфографическому словарю РАН (2015; В. В. Лопатин), *супер* - приставка, пишется слитно; но: Супер-гран-при, супер-мини-компьютер, супер-эго. Также отмечается употребление слова *супер* *(-а, мн. -ы, -ов и (разг.) супера, -ов)* в значении "суперобложка" и *(неизм.)* в значение "высшая оценка чего-либо" *(снижен.)*.

Приведенные вами примеры дефисного написания в своем большинстве неверны. К примеру, *суперпрофессионал* пишется слитно. Супермегаадекватный стоит писать именно так: *супер* + *мегаадекватный* (*мега* - приставка; международные префиксы типа *гипер-*, *макро-* принято писать слитно). Появление дефиса в таких словах возможно только в двух случаях: 1) Это исключение (супер-эго); 2) Слово, к которому присоединяется приставка, уже пишется через дефис (супер-гран-при).

Также к вашему переводу латинского *super* стоит добавить *сверх* (для точности).

Будьте добры, укажите справочники, словари, в которых приводятся эти написания:

> Особенно часто слово "супер" используется для эмоционально-субъективной авторской оценки качества существительных и прилагательных, и такие слова сложно найти в словаре (пишут их через дефис или раздельно), например: супер-профессионал, супер-мультик, супер-хит, супер-хороший, супер-приобретение, супер-качество, супер-талант, супер-квартира, супер-режиссер, супер-красивый, супер-цивилизованный.

Comment: В справочниках и словарях написание слитное, кроме исключений, но там указан только  десяток слов,  в то время как в реальности их много больше. Речь идет не о словарях, а о грамотности пользователей в Сети, которые преимущественно пишут "супер" раздельно, иногда через дефис и не очень часто слитно. "Супер" -  слово с высокой частотностью употребления, и получается, что все пишут неграмотно.  А кстати, семантика слов бывает разная, что видно из такого сравнения: (1) супер квартира  и квартир супер (это определение); (2) суперпрофессионал, только один вариант , и это приставка.

Comment: Также отметим, что эта проблем касается  и других слов, например "онлайн". Здесь уже предлагается дефисное написание  (онлайн-услуги, онлайн-перевод, онлайн-трансляция), но  в текстах чаще встречается раздельная форма, она уже и смотрится привычнее. Вот и не мешало бы в этой теме навести порядок, и не просто указывать, как надо писать,  а какую-никакую теорию бы приложить.

Comment: @Sibylla стоит различать слова и приставки. Если мы говорим о *супер* как о существительном, наречии или прилагательном (ср.: *Выпускаем эти [книги] с суперами*, *Как вечер? Супер?* и *Наши овощи супер!*), то применяем нужные орфографические правила, если говорим о приставке - то же самое. В чем проблема? В безграмотности, незнание правил слитно / раздельно / через дефис? Ничего нового, Америкой не пахнет. С онлайн ситуация почти такая же. Кодифицировано уже.

Comment: @Sibylla *Онлайн* пишем через дефис как первую часть сложных существительных или сочетаний с приложением, состоящих из двух частей - самостоятельно употребляющихся со вторым склоняемым компонентом, напр.: *онлайн-словарь*. Как постпозитивное несклоняемое определение пишется раздельно с предшествующим существительным, например: *скачать справочник онлайн без СМС и регистрации*. (См. Объяснительный русский орфографический словарь-справочник РАН)

Comment: Обсуждаем ТОЛЬКО ПРИЗНКОВОЕ значение слов: суперквартира - роскошная квартира, здесь "супер" назвали приставкой и пишут слитно. Онлайн-трансляция - прямая трансляция, здесь "онлайн" назвали приложением и пишут через дефис. Такие двойные стандарты непонятны российскому пользователю,  а раздельная форма написания английских слов в препозиции кажется удобной и  логичной.  Поэтому правила есть, но ими не пользуются  или пользуются только в  официальных случаях. Такое вот противостояние: кто кого.

Comment: @Sibylla боюсь, это ваше мнение и ваше представление, навряд ли так и есть. Вы говорите о грамматике, семантике... и не понимаете (похоже)  разницу между *супер* и *онлайн*. Что значит "двойные стандарты"?! (Противное выражение!) Как это "назвали приложением"?! "Назвали приставкой"? Хулить правила нужно с осторожностью и с обоснованием.

Comment: Похоже,  мы плохо понимаем друг друга, поэтому давайте воздержимся от личностных оценок и завершим нашу беседу. В любом случае, я с уважением отношусь к Вашему мнению.

Comment: @Sibylla да, у меня сложилось похожее чувство.